# How to fix unregonize statement type error?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

[image]I can't use savepoint,rollback,commit commands with phpmyadmin which runs on wamp.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot actually shows a warning* from phpMyAdmin, but if you click on "Go" it will still submit the query, which will execute correctly if your database supports it. In this case, the parser used by phpMyAdmin doesn't know how to correctly show the SAVEPOINT syntax, so it's warning you that something is beyond its ability to check.

However, my understanding of this functionality is that it's only valid for the current session. Since phpMyAdmin starts a new session each time you run a new query, this probably won't accomplish what you expect.

* I'd consider a warning different from an error in that a warning lets you continue and is often advice that something may not be as expected; an error is something that is definitely wrong and it won't let you proceed.